# Prove that all of the following sets have the same cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have encountered the following problem:

Prove that the following sets have the same cardinality using Cantor-Bernstein theorem, or by showing a bijection:
$$P(\mathbb{N}), \mathbb{N}\times P(\mathbb{N}), P(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$$

The first part of the proof is simple using the identity function. The problem arises next... I've tried to construct a lot of different functions, but neither of them were a bijection or even an injection.

Help or tips would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that there are trivial injections from $P(\mathbb{N})$ to $\mathbb{N}\times P(\mathbb{N})$ to $P(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$, the difficult part is to show an injection of $P(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$ into $P(\mathbb{N})$. The trick is to use an intermediate set, that is $P(\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N})$, which of course has the same cardinality as $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Now map a function $f\in  P(\mathbb{N})^\mathbb{N}$ to the a subset of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ as $\{(n, m) | n\in \mathbb{N}, m \in f(n)\}$.

Comment: Thanks, this helps very much! Any tips how to deal with N×P(N)?

Comment: Much easier: map an element $(n, S) \in \mathbb{N}\times P(\mathbb{N}), S\neq\emptyset$ into the function that takes all elements of $S$ into the singleton set $\{n\}$, and all other integers to the empty set. If $S$ is empty, map $(n, S)$ to the constant function $f(x) \to \{n\}$ (the previous trick wouldn't work, as all those functions would be the same function $f(x)\to\emptyset$)